# Best method to search username

Tags: search, parse-platform, query-string

I am working in Xcode obj-c and integrating with parse. I am calling a query to search a username. The issue I have is that the search is too literal, so for example if I have a username like 'Manny' I have to search with a Capitol 'M' in order for the search to find it, which isn't what I want. So how can I make the search more flexible?

Answer (score 1):

while siging up save the username as **.lowercaseString**
and when user search for it, convert the **search.text.lowercaseString** too.

Comment: Yeah that was my initial work around. But I want users to have the option of using capitols in their username. Any solution?

Comment: create one more field as "realUsername" and same what they have exactly added. Show the users "realUsername" as their username but when searching, search for "username"

Answer (score 0):

Actually just had a brain wave. Just save a copy of the username as a lowercase, search against that then simply display actual username in table view.